# How to view "Fax Activity Log" on HP Color LaserJet Pro MFP 4301

Tags: printing, printers, fax, mfp

The printer's embedded web server only has "print" option for "Fax Activity Log" as shown below. How do I view "Fax Activity Log" online and print it to a PDF? I do not want to print it on pager.

Answer (score 0):

After upgrading to the firmware version 6.17.2.2-202312091658, the fax activity report (and many other reports) are under the download tab. Previously with firmware version 6.12.x.x, only "Open Source Licenses" is under the download tab.